# How to bill for a downloadable .jar on my server? (mobile, j2me)

Tags: java, java-me, jar, app-store, billing

I would like the users to be able to download the .jar without any SMS approvals, by going to the webpage from their cellphones, being notified about the price and get billed. Is it a reliable task to be done without using any commercial app store?
Thanks.

Edit: to credit the same way as OVI bills it's users could be a great approach, does it make sense for a small company?

Comment: I would think it would depend on the operating system of the phone. Some phones have very tricky file browsers and accessing downloads and being able to work with them can be difficult for the average user.

Comment: `by going to the webpage from their cellphones, being notified about the price and get billed` how would you do it ?

Comment: For whom would you charge the amount? By what you are saying, you do not have the credit card info. Do you have some sort of agreement with the service provider?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it's possible to bill without some carrier restrictions. Imagine you download a game and it bills you *every* time you score a point. That would really hurt...

You would have to implement a activation key system of sorts in order to do something like that, but since you are dealing with a JAR file, it can be easily decompiled and cracked.

I would say that you have to stick with pay-to-download solutions. Better yet, how about make them free ;)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: no. At least I don't think so. If I would be that easy, everyone knew about it. Sorry.

- At my company, we're selling Software bundled in .exe setup files. We're using http://www.cleverbridge.com/ for the payment process. Then after the payee has paid, we give him login credentials via mail. From there on, he can user these credentials to login in a secured webpage from where he can download the file.
- On the iPhone, you can use in-app purchases if you're within an app or you can link to your app with an iTunes URL handler that sends users from MobileSafari to the appstore, but as you want to sell .jars I guess that doesn't help you too ;-)

Comment: I checked few eCommerce solutions, but selling an app or a software license worldwide seems to be nonsense with today's statistics on piracy and bought software. Does your company have a success with selling its software?

Comment: Yes. Even if a big amount of users may have pirated their copies, there are enough legal buyers. Setting up ads and a website and doing the necessary marketing stuff isn't all too easy, but it seems to pay off well enough as we're expanding.  You can find us at http://www.abelssoft.net